# Using "ssh -Y" on Os X

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, xorg

How can I display remote applications on OS X via ssh? If I try, I get the error "Could not open display". Im trying to access Raspbian (Debian) from OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Do you have a running X-server on the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have XQuartz installed? That will give you the ability to run remote XWindows sessions via SSH. After it's installed, running "ssh -Y username@server.name.here" then starting a XWindows session should work.

[XQuartz is available from here.](http://xquartz.macosforge.org)